# ckeditor sortable with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, angular-ui

I'm using with CKEditor to provide users write on my website.
I'm using ng-repeat and also insert a button to add a new CKEditor.
I need to provide them to sort all CKEditors and I'm trying to do so with angular UI sortable.

The problem is when the user tries to sort each one of CK-editor all the text is disappear and lock to edit area.

There is [an example on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CcOJVFogEOOenaJZ0EQs?p=preview).

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mainCtlr">
{{editorList |json}}
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div ui-sortable ng-model="editorList">
  <div ng-repeat="item in editorList" style="border: 1px solid red; margin: 10px;">
    <textarea class="ckeditor" ng-model="item.text" mh-ck></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<ul ui-sortable ng-model="editorList">
  <li ng-repeat="item in editorList">{{ item.id }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `opposites to blank`?

Comment: The text inside the editor is disapear.

Comment: I found the solution, need to destroy instance of ckeditor on start of sort, and create new one on the end.

[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/485ldGUuuNtcd51R6ptY?p=preview)